# Finding rows relation in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table PC with columns `name` and `price`.

I want to display every pc's name and the total number of other pc's in the table which have a bigger price,how can I do that?

Comment: Please update your post with what you have tried and what isn't working so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery that selects all PCs with a higher price and counts them in an aggregation.

```
SELECT pc1.name,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM pc pc2
               WHERE pc2.price > pc1.price)
       FROM pc pc1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can self-join the table and use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.name, p.price, COALESCE(COUNT(p1.name), 0) cnt
FROM pc p
LEFT JOIN pc p1 ON p1.price > p.price
GROUP BY p.name, p.price
```

In MySQL 8.0, you also use window functions, which are usually more efficient than aggregation or correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    p.name, 
    p.price, 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY price DESC) - 1 rn
FROM pc p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  pc1.name,
  (select count(*) from PC pc2 where pc2.price > pc1.price) as count_bigger_price
from PC pc1
```